# cast string to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

I have asp.net Calendar to select the date 'selectedDate' and time Piker to select time 'starttime ' I am trying to add the 2 strings 1 startTime object 'startDateTime'

```
        string strDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString(); ;
        string startTime = txtb_endTimeManual.Text;
        DateTime startDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate + startTime);
```

error message
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: if you show actual string values of strDate and startTime it would help a lot, but you could start by adding a space inbetween those two values Convert.ToDateTime(strDate + " " + startTime);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a space between the two strings. If strDate is '1/15/2012' and startTime is '6:30:00 PM' then concatenating the two strings give you '1/15/20126:30:00 PM' so the format is all off.

```
DateTime startDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate + " " + startTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the inputs it's hard to say whether you can trust they are formatted properly but, beyond that, I would say that you don't have a space between your date and time in the `Convert.ToDateTime()` method call.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a conversion to a string, a string concat, and another conversion, the Calendar already returns a DateTime object. You can set the time.

```
string startTime = txtb_endTimeManual.Text;
DateTime startDateTime = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(startTime));
```